# Двойное обращения к репозиторию

Tags: java, jpa

Является ли хорошим тоном двойное обращение к репозиторию в рамках одного метода? Приведет ли это к нагрузке на базу данных, при условии, что в репозитории вызывается поиск, например, по логину и почте? Есть ли плюсы у такого подхода? Прошу дать объяснение

```
    public void findUser(String login, String email) {
        repository.findByLogin(login);
        repository.findByEmail(email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вопросы такого рода не имеют однозначного ответа.  Если у вас есть некая бизнес-логика, требующая нескольких обращений к базе через один или несколько репозиториев, это вполне допускается.  С другой стороны, некий гуру - борец со сложностью кода может потребовать принудительного разделения логики, чтобы каждый метод в сервисе не обращался более одного раза.  Нагрузка на базу данных -- это отдельный вопрос, для её снижения поля, по которым выполняяется поиск, следует проиндексировать.

Comment: К репозиторию обращается интерактор. В интеракторе ведь это единый метод, верно? Но мне не понятен смысл таких вызовов: функция ничего не возвращает и никак не использует результат... То бишь если какая-то бизнес логика заложена в сам "репозиторий" - это уже не репозиторий как таковой, а вообще какой-то usecase... Подмена понятий отдаляет от "Clean arch"